# GUI interface to preview opencv changes

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, asynchronous, tkinter

I am new to python and I am trying to learn openCV, so in order to see and analyse the frames on the video I wanted to make a simple GUI interface using tkinter to have the basic controls of a video like play, pause step and loop, my problem in the code below is when I click play, everything is blocked by the process, and I am no more able to click pause or any of the buttons, please any suggestion on how can I achieve this to run it asynchronuosly.

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2

def play():
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture('480.m4v')

  while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame1 = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("feed", frame1)

    if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
        break

  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  cap.release()


def pause():
  print(var1.get())


def step():
  print(var1.get())

root = Tk()
root.title('GUI Control')
root.geometry('700x400')

# Play Button
play_btn = Button(root, text="Play", width=12, command=play)
play_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
# Pause Button
pause_btn = Button(root, text="Pause", width=12, command=pause)
pause_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20, padx=20)
# Step Button
pause_btn = Button(root, text="Step", width=12, command=step)
pause_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=20)

var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Loop Playing", variable=var1).grid(
    row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not if it is the best aproach but I used threading and it is working as expected here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
import threading

def vid():
    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('480.m4v')

        while cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame1 = cap.read()
            if ret == False:
                break
            cv2.imshow("feed", frame1)

            if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
                break

        loop = var1.get()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()

def playFunc():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=vid)
    t1.start()

def pauseFunc():
    print(var1.get())

def stepFunc():
    print(var1.get())

root = Tk()
root.title('GUI Control')
root.geometry('700x400')

# Play Button
play_btn = Button(root, text="Play", width=12, command=playFunc)
play_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
# Pause Button
pause_btn = Button(root, text="Pause", width=12, command=pauseFunc)
pause_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20, padx=20)
# Step Button
pause_btn = Button(root, text="Step", width=12, command=stepFunc)
pause_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=20)

var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Loop Playing", variable=var1).grid(
    row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```